# Put this text in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

I wanna put `res` into an `array[google, Rue Abdallaye, null, Trarza, null, 18.0951362, -15.9806735, MR, true]`. How do I do that? Thanks.

```
>> puts res
Provider: google
Street: Rue Abdallaye
City: 
State: Trarza
Zip: 
Latitude: 18.0951362
Longitude: -15.9806735
Country: MR
Success: true
=> nil
>> res.kind_of?(Array)
=> false
>> res.inspect
=> "#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1021f10c8 @city=nil, @province=\"Nouakchott\", @country=\"Mauritania\", @street_address=\"Rue Abdallaye\", @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x101f9f8d8 @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101f9f748 @lng=-15.9793232, @lat=18.0964779>, @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101f9f810 @lng=-15.9820212, @lat=18.0937799>>, @country_code=\"MR\", @state=\"Trarza\", @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1021f10c8 ...>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x101f9f5e0 @city=\"Nouakchott\", @province=nil, @country=\"Mauritania\", @street_address=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x101d624a8 @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101d62458 @lng=-15.9793232, @lat=18.0964779>, @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101d62480 @lng=-15.9820212, @lat=18.0937799>>, @country_code=\"MR\", @state=\"Nouakchott\", @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x101f9f5e0 ...>], @accuracy=4, @lng=-15.9993672, @full_address=\"Tevragh Zeina, Nouakchott, Mauritania\", @provider=\"google\", @precision=\"city\", @zip=nil, @lat=18.110344, @success=true>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x101d62048 @city=\"Nouakchott\", @province=nil, @country=\"Mauritania\", @street_address=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x101506f70 @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101506ef8 @lng=-15.9793232, @lat=18.0964779>, @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101506f20 @lng=-15.9820212, @lat=18.0937799>>, @country_code=\"MR\", @state=\"Nouakchott\", @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x101d62048 ...>], @accuracy=4, @lng=-15.97842, @full_address=\"Nouakchott, Mauritania\", @provider=\"google\", @precision=\"city\", @zip=nil, @lat=18.084061, @success=true>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1015069d0 @city=nil, @province=\"نواكشوط\", @country=\"Mauritania\", @street_address=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x101274e10 @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101274c58 @lng=-15.9793232, @lat=18.0964779>, @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x101274de8 @lng=-15.9820212, @lat=18.0937799>>, @country_code=\"MR\", @state=\"ولاية الترارزة\", @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1015069d0 ...>], @accuracy=3, @lng=-15.92299, @full_address=\"Nouakchott, Mauritania\", @provider=\"google\", @precision=\"state\", @zip=nil, @lat=18.1801386, @success=true>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x101274af0 @city=nil, @province=nil, @country=\"Mauritania\", @street_address=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x1005b4658 @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x1005b4608 @lng=-15.9793232, @lat=18.0964779>, @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x1005b4630 @lng=-15.9820212, @lat=18.0937799>>, @country_code=\"MR\", @state=\"Nouakchott\", @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x101274af0 ...>], @accuracy=2, @lng=-15.92299, @full_address=\"Nouakchott, Mauritania\", @provider=\"google\", @precision=\"state\", @zip=nil, @lat=18.1801386, @success=true>, #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1005b41d0 @city=nil, @province=nil, @country=\"Mauritania\", @street_address=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x10349e040 @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x10349dff0 @lng=-15.9793232, @lat=18.0964779>, @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x10349e018 @lng=-15.9820212, @lat=18.0937799>>, @country_code=\"MR\", @state=nil, @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1005b41d0 ...>], @accuracy=1, @lng=-10.940835, @full_address=\"Mauritania\", @provider=\"google\", @precision=\"country\", @zip=nil, @lat=21.00789, @success=true>], @accuracy=6, @lng=-15.9806735, @full_address=\"Rue Abdallaye, Nouakchott, Mauritania\", @provider=\"google\", @precision=\"zip+4\", @zip=nil, @lat=18.0951362, @success=true>"
```

Comment: what's the kind of `res.first`? (you'll have your answer then)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://geokit.rubyforge.org/api/geokit-gem/Geokit/GeoLoc.html

```
ary = [res.provider, res.street_name, res.city, res.state, res.zip, res.lng, res.lat, res.country_code, res.success]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get a hash from a Geokit::GeoLoc object with `res.to_hash`, and with `res.to_hash.values` you will get an array.

If you are using Ruby 1.9 the hash key order will be preserved, otherwise you should sort the hash by yourself before getting the values into an array.

Bests,

Richard